# Reverse Relationship in django AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'Tax_Master_id'

Tags: model, relationship

I have two Models Tax Master and Tax Group. in my sales view need to fetch the tax Name and percentage of each tax master for a tax group.

when i am trying to get the tax master item, it gives error 'dict' object has no attribute 'Tax_Master_id' (I also tried with Tax_Master__id with no luck)

Model:

```
class product_Master(models.Model):
    company          = models.ForeignKey(company_Master,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')  
    product_Code     = models.CharField(max_length=12,default='')
    product_Name     = models.CharField(max_length=80,default='')
    product_STaxGrp  = models.CharField(max_length=3,default="")
    product_PTaxGrp  = models.CharField(max_length=3,default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_Name + '(' + self.product_MktBy + ')'

  class Tax_Master(models.Model):
    Tax_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    Tax_percetage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=3, default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Tax_name #+ "-" + str(self.Tax_percetage)

class Tax_Group(models.Model):
    company     = models.ForeignKey(company_Master,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='') 
    Tax_GrpCd   = models.CharField(max_length=3,default="")
    Tax_Group   = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    Tax_Master  = models.ForeignKey(Tax_Master,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Tax_GrpCd)  + "-" + self.Tax_Group
```

View:

```
objProd = product_Master.objects.filter(product_Code = Code).first()
  objSTaxGrp = Tax_Group.objects.filter(
    company_id = objComp[0], 
    Tax_GrpCd = objProd.product_STaxGrp).values() 
    print(objSTaxGrp[0].Tax_Master_id)
```

Error:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'Tax_Master_id'

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by myself but any further suggestions are welcome.

```
        objSTaxGrp = Tax_Group.objects.filter(company_id = objComp[0], Tax_GrpCd = objProd.product_STaxGrp).values() 
        for obj in objSTaxGrp:
            print(obj['Tax_Master_id'])
```

Regards,
A